# convert object to string getting can not cast error

Tags: java

I have a list of object List in which at 4th index it has list of integer [1,2,3,4,5]
Now I want to get list into a comma separated string.
below is my try, but it giving error as can not cast.

```
for(Object[] objArr : relationshipInfo){
if(null != objArr[4]){
String groupedItemIds = (String)objArr[4];
}
```

how to do this?

Comment: Do you know that each object is having `toString()` method?

Comment: you are doing it the wrong way
1/ why for loop when you know you want fourth element
2/ use **toArray()** instead 
3/ Cannot type cast Integer to String | use String.valueOf()

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:- use **toString()**

```
String output = relationshipInfo.toString();
output = output.replace("[", "");
output = output.replace("]", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

**[UPDATE]**

If you want fourth Object only then try:

```
    Object[] objArr = relationshipInfo.toArray();
    String groupedItemIds = String.valueOf(objArr[4]);
```

Comment: relationshipInfo is an array of which he wants the 4th index.

Comment: I tried some to sugessions  but always getting  java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String exception.

Comment: @user2310289 u can upVote now :D
neways thanx

Comment: I resolved by byte[] groupedItemIdsArr = (byte[])objArr[4];
     String groupedItemIds = new String(groupedItemIdsArr);

Answer (score 0):

Integer Array or Integer can not be cast to a String.

try

```
for(Object[] objArr : relationshipInfo){
if(null != objArr[4]){
 String groupedItemIds =  new String (objArr[4]); // or String.valueOf(objArr[4]);
}
```

**Update**

If the 4th index is a Array then try

```
String groupedItemIds = Arrays.asList(objArr[4]).toString();
```

which will give you a comma delimitered String

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an Object to an uncomatible type

```
for(Object[] objArr : relationshipInfo){
if(null != objArr[4]){
List<Integer> groupedItemIds = (List<Integer)objArr[4];;

//Loop over the integer list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot type cast Object to String unless the Object is indeed a String. Instead you can do the following -

Call `toString()` on it.  Override it in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for(Object[] objArr : relationshipInfo)
{
      if(null != objArr[4])
       {
          String groupedItemIds = String.valueOf(objArr[4]);
       }
}
```

Ref :

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj)
```

Returns the string representation of the Object argument.
[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

Difference between use of `toString()` and `String.valueOf()`

if you invoke `toString()` with a `null` object or null value, you'll get a `NullPointerExcepection` whereas using `String.valueOf()` you don't have to check for `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

you want "comma separated string" . So, you iterate over the 4th index and read each integer and do "" + int1 +" , " + int2 etc.. you can do this (in) by overriding your toString() method..

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
String groupedItemIds = Arrays.asList( objArr[4] ).toString();
```

This will produce: `groupedItemIds = "[1,2,3,4,5]"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using arrays not Lists in which case you can use:

```
String groupedItemIds = java.util.Arrays.toString(objArr[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by belwo code

```
byte[] groupedItemIdsArr = (byte[])objArr[4];
String groupedItemIds = new String(groupedItemIdsArr);
```